# Using iFrames instead of Frame

Tags: iframe, frames

My web site is based on a Frameset with 5 frames. 3 Frames remain unchanged. Clicking on a hyperlink within the web site changes two of the frames. I understand that Frames will become redundant with html5 but I'm not entirely sure what this means and whether my web site will cease to function in the future.

To try to prepare for this I am looking at changing the web site to iFrames. I've managed to create the page using css and iFrames. I now need to know how to change my code so that hyperlinks change the two iFrames. As an example, my current code for the hyperlink is, for example:

```
<a href="javascript:loadyear('frm_calendar_prep.php','frm_right_calendar_comps_title.php')" 
class="menu_link" ><span class="main_body_AGM_blue">Competitions</span>,</a>
```

Then I have the following javascript function

```
function loadmain(filetoload,titletoload) {
parent.mainFrame.location=filetoload
parent.titleFrame.location=titletoload
 }
```

where mainFrame and titleFrame are the two frames being changed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that `<frame>` will not be *redundant*. It's entirely obsolete and has been for several years.

Answer (score 0):

When I developed this web site 20 years ago, all the magazines and articles were recommending the use of framesets and frames. They are simple to code and, compared to css and iframes, have very few lines of code. Most importantly they halve the load time of the next page etc.But, sadly, the authorities have decided that they are now obsolete. I need to find how I can convert my web site.